# BotFramework - handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch URL not working

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Below is the continue task module I am returning. The URL works fine when I hit it directly in the browser, but in teams, I always get this:

[image]

**Task module reponse**

```js
handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch() {
  return {
    task: {
      type: "continue",
      value: {
        title: "response",
        url: `${process.env.HostName}/help.html`,
        fallbackUrl: `${process.env.HostName}/help.html`,
        width: 500,
        height: 500
      }
    }
  };
}
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Cheers

**Note**: This is how I am creating the Adaptive Card

```js
const adaptiveCard = {
  $schema: 'http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json',
  version: '1.0',
  type: 'AdaptiveCard',
  body: [{
    type: 'TextBlock',
    text: 'Task Module Invocation from Adaptive Card',
    weight: 'bolder',
    size: 3
  }],
  actions: [{
    type: 'Action.Submit',
    title: "TEST",
    data: { msteams: { type: 'task/fetch'}, data: "meTask" }
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The URL's domain must be in the app's [validDomains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#validdomains) array in your app's manifest.